# Weight factor - control via keyboard

Tags: customization, shortcut, weight-painting

I have a question regarding Weight Paint mode.
I would like to have control over Weight factor via keyboard. Specifically I would like to assign value "1" of that factor to the one key and value "0" to another. I don't see that kind of shortcuts in User Preferences panel (in the Input section I found only <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> for Set Weight). There's Add New button there but I don't know how to define mentioned values "1" and "0" for Weight factor. If you could help me with that, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

To change the ***Weight*** value press <kbd>W</kbd> (being in *Weight Paint* mode) and drag the cursor inward/outwards the small circle showing the weight value. After pressing <kbd>W</kbd> you may also type the value using numerical keyboard (e.g. you press <kbd>W</kbd>, then <kbd>1</kbd>) and the weight value changes to 1).
[image]

Remember that you may also use shortcuts to change the ***Radius*** (press <kbd>F</kbd>) and ***Strenght*** values (press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>). Use these to work faster.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Paul for your time and (very) quick answer. Unfortunately this is not exactly what I'm chasing. I know about possibilities hidden behind W key (as well as F and Shift + F) and it's quite fast. Especially combination "W" and "1" to set weight factor to "1". It is closest to what I would like to have. But... to set it to "0" I have to move my hand over whole keyboard to "0", which is not so fast and require constant hand movement... instead of only fingers movement with wrist based on the edge of my laptop. It seems to be not a big deal, but... I'm simply trying to achieve the fastest and most ergonomic workflow.

Ideally I would like to have something similar to my settings in Gimp when I'm drawing in grayscale - set "Z" (or some other key close to left bottom of a keyboard) to maximum Weight and "X" to minimum Weight. And then quickly switching between them without moving whole hand over the keyboard (with adjustments of Strength from time to time and "enabled tablet pressure sensitivity for strength").

Anyway - thank you again for taking time and trying to help me. If my most desired setting won't possible, then probably the next closest workflow will be combination W and 1 / W and 0.

Best Regards

Jonatan

Answer (score 0):

### Binding a key press to set a property to a certain value

You can bind a key press to set a property value using one of the `wm.context_set_XXX` operators; in this case `wm.context_set_float`, since Weight is a float value.  For [the full list of operators](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.context_set_float), see the latest version of the Blender documentation.

The context set operators take a data path and a value.  The data path, also called context attribute, in this case would be `tool_settings.unified_paint_settings.weight`, which can be found by right-clicking on the Weight value in the user interface and selecting Copy Data Path.

[image]

Comment: Thank you - looks like a step in desired direction. I've assigned 0 to Z and 1 to X and it works perfectly.. but only once..
It looks like that: I'm starting new file and default value for Weight is 1. When I press Z it changes to 0. When I press X - it changes back to 1 and thats it. When I press Z again, the value stays 1. When I change it manually to 0 and then I press either Z or X it changes to 1 and stays like that. After reloading startup file - the same story: it works once and then stops working. What I could've do wrong?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Jonatan

Comment: I've assigned those keys and it seems to override the defaults I had setup on those keys.  I am unable to replicate your fault unfortunately, it works flawlessly for me on Z and X.  Have you got the correct values set in the sliders?  Is Relative checked by accident?  Are you using Unified Weight settings across all brushes?

Comment: Yes - the values are set to 0 for Z and 1 for X. Relative is not checked. I have Weight box checked for "Unified Settings" under "Options" menu (I assume that this is what you meant) but when I unchecked it, Z/X stopped work completely (not even once)...