# Key/shortcut to change weight value when weight painting?

Tags: weight-painting

I found an old question that says the W key can be used to change the weight value, but that doesn't seem to work in v2.79 anymore. The F key and Shift + F still work in changing the radius and strength, but the W key only brings up the specials menu.

[Weight factor - control via keyboard](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51034/weight-factor-control-via-keyboard) Here is the question/answer that I mentioned

Comment: can you add a link to the question mentioned?

Comment: I find this particularly useful: https://www.giudansky.com/illustration/infographics/blender-map

Comment: @cegaton I added the link

Comment: It works in 2.79b, I tried that now. Maybe you assigned the shortcut to some different function?

Answer (score 6):

In Blender 2.93 you need to use **Ctrl + F** to change brush weight.

I know I'm a bit late but maybe this will help somebody.

Comment: It helped, thanks)